# Layouts personalizados Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Como puedo realizar dos contenedores dentro de un layout que tengo creado. La idea es tratar de hacer algo similar a lo remarcado en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Idea]

Y tratar de insertar algo similar en el topLinearLayout de mi codigo

[image: Concepto]

En esos cajetines insertare el valor mas rentable con un fonde verde y el cajetin que le acompaña con un fonde rojo mostrara el valor menos rentable

CÓDIGO:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvListaDeBotones"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noticiasButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Noticias"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/estadoButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Estado"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final String[] TITULOS_BTN =
        new String[] { "IBEX 35", "AENA", "BANCO SABADELL", "BANCO  SANTANDER",
                "CAIXABANK", "GAS NATURAL", "FERROVIAL", "IBERDROLA", "TELEFONICA",
                "AMAZON", "MICROSOFT CORPORATION", "APPLE", "NASDAQ", "ORO", "PETROLEO"};

public ListView lvListaDeBotones;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvListaDeBotones = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvListaDeBotones);
    MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, TITULOS_BTN);
    lvListaDeBotones.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    lvListaDeBotones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Aquí puedes capturar en on Click de la vista que se crea en general.
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copia y pega el código desde la linea que comenté para crear cuantos necesites. Recuerda ponerle Ids a los TextViews, cambiarle el color, agregarle el texto y el tamaño de la fuente que desees.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/saldo"
            android:textColor="@color/letra"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- AREA PARA COPIAR INICIO-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/saldoLinearLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Turn over"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Turn over"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Turn over"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Turn over"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
   <!-- AREA PARA COPIAR FIN -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/midTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvListaDeBotones"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/midTableLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Home" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/noticiasButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Noticias"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/estadoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Estado"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Déjame saber si te funcionó.

Comment: muchas gracias ;D